# Ensure all elements in List<T> types are T

Tags: c#, .net, oop, generics, .net-2.0

I want to verify that all the `List<T>`'s elements types are `T`.

I can have a `List<object>` containing object, string, int, Product, Supplier etc', but in my case, if the `List<T>` was defined as `List<object>` all the elements must be objects.

That is, I want to ensure that the type of the elements is the *exact* type of the passed in generic type, not anything else in the inheritance chain.

Example:

```
public void Foo<T>(List<T> list)
{
    // if not all elements are of type T (not SubClass of T) throw exception

    //...    
}
```

What is the best way?

Comment: I would probably do this up front and create a class that contains my list of objects. Upon insertion, I would guarantee that the type being added was in the approved list.

Comment: I am curious why you wouldnt just create List<int> when you need a list of ints and a List<Supplier> if you need a list of suppliers and so on.  By doing List<object> you are kinda defeating the purpose of generics, unless you actually did want a list of all those different types.  But if that were the case you wouldnt be asking the question I would think.

Comment: This design is a very bad idea - derived classes should typically be handled the same way as the base class in this scenario - **why** would you want to have this test?

Comment: @Etch, I have a method that makes a Excel sheet based on the class properties attributes. Any class is allowed, but two classes are not allowed, so T and subclass T doesn't fit in one excel sheet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming if `T` is a base class you want to disallow derived classes.

```
if(list.Any(element => element.GetType() != typeof(T))
    throw new ArgumentException();
```

Comment: I would have never thought to use linq here.  Clever.

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this is what you are after:

```
public static Boolean AssertNoSubtypes<T>(List<T> items) {
    return items.All(i=>i.GetType().Equals(typeof(T)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the exact type by using `typeof` and `Object.GetType()`.  For example:

```
foreach(T item in list)
{
    if(! typeof(T).Equals(item.GetType())
    {
        /* Throw */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Oded, but if you want to have sure or treat each element itself you can use a foreach.

```
foreach(object item in list)
{
    //whatever you want
}
```

You can add a random number of objects and put a breakpoint in this line, so count by yourself how much times it entered....or simply declare a count and check if it has the same number of items you added.

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense.  If the list contains N items, the foreach loop will either execute N times or throw.  Absent an exception, the count of foreach loop iterations and of list items will always be the same.